# django admin custom form validation

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to validate image in django admin using form validation.

models.py

```
class website_index(models.Model):
  screenshot=models.ImageField(storage=AzureStorage(container="media"),upload_to='search/resources/screenshots/',blank=True,null=True)
```

admin.py

```
class CustomIndexModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = website_index
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_image(self):
        screenshot = self.cleaned_data.get['screenshot']
        if screenshot:    
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(screenshot)
            if w!=h :
                raise forms.ValidationError('Upload a square image')
        return screenshot

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomIndexModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['parent_id'].queryset = cat_tree.objects.exclude(level=0)

class website_index_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomIndexModelForm
```

I have seen other answers and I am ensuring those points, still django is not raising any Validation error when I upload image that violate the validation rules.

Comment: You are not cleaning the field screenshot, try def clean_screenshot - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: You may also use (my) package for [image validation](https://github.com/manikos/django-vimage).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field name is **screenshot**. **clean_image** never gets executed. You need to change the method name to **clean_screenshot**.